# elementor pro - menu cart - link getting broken by popup cart

Tags: wordpress, cart, elementor

Im using elementor pro, I have a header that has the menu cart in there and all works fine, but the mobile header is different and I am trying to add the menu cart as a popup icon on page load. When i do this it breaks the link of the desktop header menu cart even though the popup is hidden on desktop. how can i fix this?

I am open to suggestions, not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

its okay i realised the code was conflicting with one another for the popup cart and the header cart and causing the issue so i put advanced rule for the popup to only display on mobile rather than just responsively hiding the section on desktop and now all works fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).